# Is there a way to run a java stream without returning anything?

Tags: java

Sometimes I want to use Java streams to run an operation against each element, like this:

```java
List.of("a", "b", "c")
     .stream()
     .peek(System.out::println)
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As you can see, I just want to print each element, there's no need for me to collect the result into a list. But if I remove the last line, the stream won't be executed at all. So my question is, is there any to run the stream without collecting the result? Something like `run()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use `forEach` loop as below:

```
List.of("a", "b", "c")
 .stream()
 .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Assuming that the OP is simply going to consume the stream, the function could be `x -> {}`.

Answer (score 4):

[StreamApi](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stream-in-java/) has two type of methods

1. **Intermediate Operations**: Methods of the first type change the stream

for example

> .map()
> .filter()

2. **Terminal Operations:** Second type finishing stream

for example

> ```
> .forEach()
> .collect()
> ```

You need use second type.

**Stream always ends with a method that ends the stream.**